# Widget post-configuration

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing an App Widget with configuration Activity. Everything works fine and a widget is correctly configured when I put it on the home screen.

Now, I want the user to be able to click on the widget and open again the configuration activity to change, for example, the text on the widget itself.

Do I have to store the new text on Preferences and force an update of the widget? Or is there a simpler way, for example accessing the RemoteViews directly on the configuration activity?

Thanks.